# Angularjs: Services and ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I use an angular service for rendering a map and I injected it into my controller. By using ui.router, when I go to map page for first time, the map renders successfully, but when routing to other page and come back to map page again, the map does not renders, and I should refresh the page for it. I used both `factory` and `service` for it, but still there is a problem! Any idea? Here is my service and controller:

```
    angular.module('app')
    .service('mapService', function () {
        var _map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map-canvas',
            renderer: 'canvas'
        });
        this.map = function () {
            return _map;
        };
    }
    .controller("mapCtrl", ["$scope", "mapService", function($scope, mapService) {
        var map = mapService.map();
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use service for DOM related changes and initialising map is DOM related action. instead, use directive for this.

See the below example, I have used open layer map and ui.router to show how you can do the same with directive.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.run(function($templateCache) {
  var homeHtml = '<div>' +
    '<h4>Rome Page</h4>' +
    '<p> this is rome </p>' +
    '<div> <ol-map center="rome"></ol-map> </div>' +
    '</div>';
  $templateCache.put('rome.html', homeHtml);

  var otherHtml = '<div>' +
    '<h4>Bern Page</h4>' +
    '<p> this is bern</p>' +
    '<div> <ol-map center="bern"></ol-map> </div>' +
    '</div>';
  $templateCache.put('bern.html', otherHtml);
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/rome");

  $stateProvider.state('rome', {
    url: "/rome",
    templateUrl: "rome.html",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.rome = ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.5, 41.9]);
    }
  }).state('bern', {
    url: "/bern",
    templateUrl: "bern.html",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.bern = ol.proj.fromLonLat([7.4458, 46.95]);
    }
  });
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

});

app.directive('olMap', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      center: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {

      scope.map = new ol.Map({
        view: new ol.View({
          center: scope.center,
          zoom: 6
        }),
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
              layer: 'osm'
            })
          })
        ],
        target: ele[0]
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
ol-map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="rome">Rome</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ui-sref="bern">Bern</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

To get `map` instance from directive, callback can be used from directive with map instance value once map is initialised. working code can be seen here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/apuq8vde/).

Comment: Great complete answer! Thanks! How can I access to the map object in a controller or another directive (for example "marker")?

Comment: You can trigger `initialized` callback from directive once map is initialized. see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/apuq8vde/

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin, http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/,
I am using it, it has complete tools for creating Map